# Are rotes tied to an order?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Each spell has one or two rotes from different orders.  Is this implying only that mages of that order can cast that rote? This is ignoring the ones where it openly says other orders use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From page 131:

> Each effect is listed with a sample rote from one of the five major orders. **Rotes are not exclusive to any single order**; most orders have their own versions of known spells. **The Skill listed for a rote’s dice pool, however, does not change from order to order**. It’s a trait inherent to the spell, and not dependent upon one particular order’s own unique means of casting. **Different orders might use different Attributes, though.** Generally, **the order most known for using that rote is listed.** Sometimes another order’s alternate means of casting a rote is described. For those orders not mentioned, assume they use the same dice pool as the primary order described for that rote.

So, as detailed, the rote version of the spell listed is the one most commonly seen and most tailored to the Order that developed it. A different order may have a variant of the rote, which will use the same Skill but may use a different Attribute.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that mages can also learn rotes from grimoires regardless of order. *Grimoire of Grimoires* (p. 16-30) even describes a series of fantasy novels that contain rotes stolen from multiple orders.